# Unclear Google Analytics API quota restrictions

Tags: google-analytics, gdata-api, google-analytics-api, web-analytics, quota

I've been recently fixing my application that apparently reached some GA quota 
limitations and I've found a couple of things that were not clear to 
me:

- Does the *4 concurrent requests* limitation apply per application, 
  per web property or anything else?
- If we break the *10 requests in any given 1-second period* or *4 
  concurrent requests* limitation, how long does it take before GA stops 
  responding with 503 ServiceUnavailable error?
- Does quota per application refer to the application name string 
  only? We are running two different web application using different GA 
  application string. Both apps connect GA API from the same IP address. 
  Can we expect the *quota per application* is calculated for each 
  application string separately in this case?
- Are the status codes sent with 503 ServiceUnavailable response 
  documented anywhere? Can we be sure that *rateLimitExceeded* refers to 
  the 10 requests per second limitation? How can I found out the cause 
  of an 503 response?

Btw is it possible that a stronger quota restrictions than documented 
may take effect sometimes?

For example, is it possible that GA replies with 503 ServiceUnavailable
response just after 6 fast but *subsequent* requests or just because of any 
other undesired behavior of a client application that's not included 
in the documentation?

Regards,

Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just been [answered](http://groups.google.com/group/google-analytics-data-export-api/browse_thread/thread/4ecd214053f7e925/d50348c92ce588e1#d50348c92ce588e1) by Nick in the GA Google Group.

Main points: the 10 qps and 4 parallel requests limitation count per IP, even an application running on a different machine in the same network may be counted.

I've submitted a documentation [bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2408) to the GData issue tracker.